# Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Program'

Tags: c#, .net-core, toplevel-statement

I started a project with the [**new console template**](https://aka.ms/new-console-template) that uses [**top level statements**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements), but I wanted to add **`Program Main`** back in anyway.

However, when I add in the class like this:

```cs
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

I get the error:

```
error CS0260: Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'Program';
Another partial declaration of this type exists
```

[Other stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12866436/1366033) say to just add [`partial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods), but when I do that, I get the error:

```
warning CS7022: The entry point of the program is global code; 
ignoring 'Program.Main()' entry point
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I forgot to remove the `Console.WriteLine` at the top as well.

Top level statements ([added in C#9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)) will "compile down" into their own compiler generated `Program` class.

You can use [**sharplab** to inspect the following code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoTCUE4AUARABICmANuQPYAEA6lQE7kAmhAlANxA==):

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Which will be compiled into something that looks like this:

```cs
[CompilerGenerated]
internal class Program
{
    private static void <Main>$(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

So you have to get rid of your top level statements if you want to use `Program.Main` (and vice versa).

There can only be one entry point